# What exactly is the vertical slash function in PROLOG? Is it an operator?

Tags: list, syntax, prolog, operators, swi-prolog

while reading the documentations and testing examples of SWI PROLOG implementation I began to go deeper into lists. PROLOG lists are no different from most languages: it has a Head and a Tail.

I then learned that SWI PROLOG lists can be expressed like this:

- `[ Head | Tail ]`

The syntax is pretty simple, square brackets with a head and a tail, separated by a vertical slash `|`.

Then I started wondering: what is the meaning (the semantics) of the vertical slash `|` in PROLOG?

I know that the vertical slash is indeed a special character, but why does it necessarily have to be a vertical slash? Is it an operator? Is it used for system or language (meta) applications? What is its specific function in the language?

Comment: `|` itself is not an operator, `[|]` is. If you are familiar with any lisps, it is equivalent to `cons`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons

Comment: Yes, `|` is an operator. Check it out here: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=op/3.

Comment: _Au contraire_, @rajashekar: `|` is just an operator. Try `current_op(Precedence, Type, '|'). You don't _have_ to use it for lists (but if you did, you'd likely confuse the heck out of anybody else looking at your code.)

Comment: `|` is a (vertical) bar. It serves as a head tail separator and as an operator.

Comment: Hmm, so `|` is also a deprecated `;/2` https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%27|%27/2 .

Comment: Very interesting information about deprecation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `|` is a right-associative infix operator of precedence 1105, *right-associative* meaning that an expression like

```
 a|b|c|d
```

binds as

```
'|'( a , '|'( b , '|'( c , d ) ) )
```

rather than the left-associative binding

```
'|'( '|'( '|'( a , b ) , c ) , d )
```

It is part of Prolog's syntactic sugar for list notation. In Prolog, any non-empty list, has a single item that is denoted as its ***head***, and the remainder of the list, itself another list (which may be empty), denoted as the ***tail***. (A rather nice recursive definition, eh?)

So one can easily partition a list into its *head* and *tail* using `|`. So

```
[Head|Tail] = [a,b,c,d]
```

results in

```
Head = a
Tail = [b,c,d]
```

From my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069057/467473),

> Prolog's list notation is *syntactic sugar* on top of very simple prolog terms. Prolog lists are denoted thus:
>
> 1. The empty list is represented by the atom `[]`. Why? Because that looks like the mathematical notation for an empty list. They could have used an atom like `nil` to denote the empty list but they didn't.
> 2. A non-empty list is represented by the term `.\2`, where the first (leftmost) argument is the *head* of the list and the second (rightmost) argument is the *tail* of the list, which is, recursively, itself a list.
>
> Some examples:
>
> - An empty list: `[]` is represented as the atom it is:
>
>   ```
>     []
>   ```
> - A list of one element, `[a]` is internally stored as
>
>   ```
>     .(a,[])
>   ```
> - A list of two elements `[a,b]` is internally stored as
>
>   ```
>     .(a,.(b,[]))
>   ```
> - A list of three elements, `[a,b,c]` is internally stored as
>
>   ```
>     .(a,.(b,.(c,[])))
>   ```
>
> Examination of the head of the list is likewise syntactic sugar over the same `./2` notation:
>
> - `[X|Xs]` is identical to `.(X,Xs)`
> - `[A,B|Xs]` is identical to `.(A,.(B,Xs))`
> - `[A,B]` is (see above) identical to `.(A,.(B,[]))`

Comment: Rather, `s/'|' d/d/ `

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I don't understand what "right-associative" and "left-associative" bindings are. I know that association is a property that can be used in logical propositions. Is this the idea? Is it like a precedence order? What does it change in practice?

Comment: _Right-associative_ operators bind to the right, so `a|b|c|d` is parsed as if it were `a|(b|(c|d))`; _left-associative_ operators bind to the left, so `a|b|c|d` is parsed as if it were `((a|b)|c)|d`.

Comment: But it is just an operator: it doesn't actual _do_ anything, except in the context of list notation. Except create terms. Outside of list notation, an expression like `a|b` just creates the term `'|'(a,b)`.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you SO much for clarifying it! Now it makes total sense, thank you @NicholasCarey

Comment: Thank you for your answers and contributions, reading the information you shared made me understand things deeper.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bit of confusion b/w the usage of vertical bar `|` generally used in list pattern matching and the `|/2` operator.

I am not familiar with other prologs so this might be swi-prolog specific. Help for `'|'` states the [following](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%27%7C%27/2):

```
help('|').
:Goal1 | :Goal2
    Equivalent to ;/2. Retained for compatibility only. New code should use ;/2.
```

So, the `|` used in list notation is not this operator.

```
?- X = '[|]'(1, []).
X = [1].

?- X = '|'(1, []).
X =  (1| []).

?- [1] = '|'(1, []).
false.

?- [1] = '[|]'(1, []).
true.
```

As seen above using just `|` only creates a compound term and not a list.

Following uses Univ `=..` and makes it more clear.

```
?- X = '[|]'(a, '[|]'(b, [])).
X = [a, b].

?- [a, b, c] =.. X.
X = ['[|]', a, [b, c]].

?- deep_univ([a, b, c, d], X).
X = ['[|]', a, ['[|]', b, ['[|]', c, ['[|]', d, []]]]].
```

I have used `deep_univ/2` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678387/convert-complex-term-to-list-of-lists-and-then-back-to-term-with-modified-functo/65679313#65679313)